# Access word Document using C# on premises show on Office 365 Iframe

Tags: c#, office365

Is there anyway to access the word document which is store in you Local drive or Azure Blob or Azure Files and show it on Office 365 Iframe using C# passing the URL

Comment: I would think you could get it from azure yes (via a web app probably) but a web page doesn't normally have access to a user's local disk

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can using WOPI 
WOPI Host
The WOPI host protocol is defined at this location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh643135(v=office.12).aspx

There’s a great overview, introducing WOPI in a blog post from the Office development team here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officedevdocs/archive/2013/03/21/introducing-wopi.aspx

In addition, a good overview of the architecture in 2013 (vs. 2010) is shown here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219437.aspx

**https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6**